# List ALL GitHub enterprise repos for an organization

Tags: api, github, curl

My private github enterprise https://my.company.url/my_sub_org  has around 250 repos

which I want to list.

I tried

`$ curl -sX GET -H "Authorization: token ${mytoken}" https://my.company.url/api/v3/orgs/my_sub_org/repos?per_page=200| grep ssh_url | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'`

but it returns only 100 matching the documentation here https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories.

I also tried

> gh repo list

but returns only stuff I own

and

> gh repo my.company.url/my_sub_org

No results.

How do I list all the repos?

Answer (score 3):

I recently found the solution for listing GitHub Enterprise repos for a specific owner in an [issue](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3232).

```
$ export GH_HOST=github.company.com
$ gh repo list <org/owner>

Showing 42 of 1337 repositories in @org/owner
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet but in that documentation, it says `per_page` is "Results per page (max 100)", and `page` as "Page number of the results to fetch" so maybe you need a loop to just iterate through different pages?

Edit 1: Github has a guide about [traversing with pagination](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/traversing-with-pagination)

Comment: could you share how the modified query would look like?
I tried `curl -sX GET -H "Authorization: token ${mytoken}" https://my.company.url/api/v3/orgs/my_sub_org/repos?per_page=200?page=2| grep ssh_url | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'` but it is not returning any results.

Comment: I actually am not very sure but maybe instead of `?` use `&`, so it would be like: 
`curl -sX GET -H "Authorization: token ${mytoken}" https://my.company.url/api/v3/orgs/my_sub_org/repos?per_page=200&page=2| grep ssh_url | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'`

Comment: I just added a link to Github's guide to traversing with pagination

Comment: Was that the correct answer? I'm curious too

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work :( i will update once i find it